# Ember-velocity mixin with Ember 1.10.0-beta.2+pre.4bf76fc6 : error: you must install velocity.js before you use it

Tags: ember.js, velocity.js

Hi I am rendendering nested component. 
details
    Ember Inspector 1.6.3
    Ember 1.10.0-beta.2+pre.4bf76fc6
    Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.10
    jQuery 1.11.1
    Ember Simple Auth 0.7.1
    Ember Simple Auth Testing 0.7.1
    Ember Simple Auth Torii 0.7.1

I have installed ember-velocity-mixins using: 
npm install ember-velocity-mixin --save
//package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-velocity-mixin": "^0.2.0"
  }.
```

//parent-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
});
```

//child-component ie person-cover.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import VelocityMixin from 'ember-velocity-mixin/main';
export default Ember.Component.extend( VelocityMixin , {
    click: function() {
        alert('hellow');
    }
});
```

I am getting following errors

**Uncaught Error: You cannot modify child views while in the inBuffer state**

Templates of my application looks likes this

//parent-component.hbs

```
{{#each person in people}}
    {{person-cover person=person}}
{{/each}}
```

//child-component ie person-cover.hbs

```
<div class="like-image">
    {{person.name}}
</div>
{{yield}}
```

**second error** that confuses me

```
 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Velocity.js must be installed to use this mixin.
VM8779:2259 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'profileNode' of undefined
```

as i mentioned earlier i have installed ember-velocity-mixin.

when i remove the VelocityMixin form component

```
import Ember from 'ember';
    import VelocityMixin from 'ember-velocity-mixin/main';
    //removed VelocityMixin from below line
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
        click: function() {
            alert('hellow');
        }
    });
```